# how to solve Magento vulnerability issue

Tags: magento-1.9, security, vulnerability

Magento website scan report says that it has some issue about security in website.following scan report says about my website vulnerability.

1. vulnerability Name: Php Info File
2. vulnerability Name: Web Application Transmits login credentials without encryption
3. vulnerability Name:Basic authentication over HTTP

How to solve vulnerability from website.this above solve vulnerability points in my website.
AND other thing is website is under ssl nd secure by htttps

How to solve above points.I need some guide above points I do not understand how to approach above this points. 
All patch installed in website.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/appsec-900_addhandler.html

Comment: ok tthanks,let me check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I have no idea which report you ran, this is how you should be able to solve it:

**vulnerability Name: Php Info File**

You most certainly have a file named `phpinfo.php` in your document root (=main directory) or somewhere else. Remove this file.

**vulnerability Name: Web Application Transmits login credentials without encryption**

Buy a SSL certificate, let your provider install it and set `https://www.yourdomain.com/` as base URL and secure base URL in Magento admin.

**vulnerability Name:Basic authentication over HTTP**

Not quite where this came from, maybe you have an additional username + password box protecting your backend (`http://www.yourdomain.com/admin`)?!
This is probably defined somewhere in a `.htaccess` file or vHost. Change it from `AuthType Basic`to `AuthType Digest`.